# The data/content isn't getting displayed. Can anyone please let me know any necessary changes to render the data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question=models.CharField(max_length=600)
    option1=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option2=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option3=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    option4=models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
```

views.py

```
def Practice_all(request):
    practice = Question.objects.all()
    context={ 'question_list': practice }
    return render(request, 'practice.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    
    path("practice/", views.Practice_all, name="practice"),
    
]
```

practice.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} 
  {% for data in question_list %} 
    <li> {{ data.option1 }} </li>
    <li> {{ data.option2 }} </li>
    <li> {{ data.option3 }} </li>
  {% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

These are the Django files that I am using, the server runs perfectly but won't display anything, not even any errors, just blank. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips for debugging:

- Are you sure that the `Question` table in your database is not empty and that the problem really stems from here? Check that using `python manage.py shell` and by running `Question.objects.all()` in the shell (or use a database visualizer like DBeaver),
- Try to visualize `{{ question_list }}` under the line `{% block content %}`, outside of the `for` loop in your HTML file: does it display anything?
- Avoid using the keyword `data` to iterate `question_list`, I wonder if this variable name could not already be used in the `context` of your page since it's a very generic keyword. Choose something more explicit like "question", it will be clearer and reduce the risk of a conflict:

```py
{% for question in question_list %} 
     ...
```